# Z_DATA_ERROR when uncompress from a compiled data file

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

I'm having troubles with decompressing data from a file.
This is where I'm at:

1. Compressed a file using compress() function.

   ```
   const char data [] =
   {
   #include "file.data"
   };
   ulong srcLen = strlen(data)+1;
   ulong destLen = compressBound(srcLen); 
   char* dest = (char*) malloc(destLen);
   int res = compress2((Bytef*) dest, &destLen, (Bytef*)data, srcLen, 5);
   ```
2. took the result and put in file.

   ```
   ofstream stream;
   stream.open("/tmp/zip_file.data");
   stream << o2stream;
   stream.close();
   ```
3. did hexdump - to avoid issues with stray characters:

   ```
   hexdump -v -e '1/1 "0x%x, "' zip_file.data > /tmp/hex_zipped_file.data
   ```
4. in source code, did this:

   ```
   const char zipped_data [] =
   {
   #include "hex_zipped_file.data"
   };
   ulong destLen = 1000000;
   ulong srcLen = strlen(zipped_data)+1;
   char* o2stream = (char*) malloc(destLen);
   res = uncompress((Bytef*)o2stream, &destLen, (Bytef*)zipped_data, srcLen);
   ```
5. In "res" I've received Z_DATA_ERROR.
6. The data inside hex_zipped_file.data looks something like that:

   ```
   0xf1, 0x44, 0x4d ... etc ...
   ```

When trying to uncompress the same info, but taken from "dest" variable, that was filled by compress function, it worked.

I've compared: "dest and "zipped_data" and they have same length and contains the same chars.

The 1000000 for size is not the issue - I've tried the exact same size as the original file and it still failed.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid `const char data [] = { #include "hex_zippedfile.data" };` simply doesn't do what I am supposing you want. Can you show us a snippet how the content of this file looks like?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is right... Also, `strlen` will not work if the string contains null bytes, which is almost guaranteed to be true for any non-trivial volume of compressed data.

Comment: I've added an example of the content and not the real content as I've lost connection to my server. it's a list of HEX numbers, separated by commas and one space after each comma.